# Get the background colour of the terminal window?

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

Is it possible to get the current background colour of the terminal window? I'm attempting to dim some of the output in my display, but this only seems to work if I set the background colour, and I'd like to continue to use the same background colour that is currently set.

Answer (score 0):

That would be [`window.getbkgd`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.getbkgd).

> Return the given window’s current background character/attribute pair.